# Can't upload image on sdcard to php server

Tags: android, file, image-uploading

I've been trying to upload an image to the php server with android upload service. But the upload works only if the file is in the phone memory. If the file is on the external sd card,no luck.

```
      try {
        String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constant.URL + "/lecture/save?token=" + token)
                .addFileToUpload(f.getAbsolutePath(), "notes_image")
                .addParameter("class_code", classId)
                .addParameter("section_code", sectionNameId)
                .addParameter("subject_code", subjectNameId)
                .addParameter("lecture_title", lectureTitleEditText.getEditableText().toString())
                .addParameter("notes", lectureNotesEditText.getEditableText().toString())
                .addParameter("pdf", base64EncodedPdfString)
                .addParameter("file_extension", "pdf")
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(5)
                .startUpload();
        Toast.makeText(this, "uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error during upload", String.valueOf(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
    }
```

I think the problem is with the file path I am providing to the upload request. Here is what I've done to get the path.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            fileUriImage = data.getData();
            filePathImage = data.getData().getPath();
    String uriString = fileUriImage.toString();
    File myFile = new File(uriString);
    String asbolutePath = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.d("ABSOLUTE PATH", asbolutePath);
    if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(fileUriImage, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
        displayName = myFile.getName();
    }
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
    dir.mkdir();
    File f = new File(dir, displayName);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        try {
            f.createNewFile();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("error creating file", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please check whether you declare in your manifest:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: what's the error messages as shown in logcat?

Comment: @CaoMinhVu Yes I've provided all the permission

Comment: @ariefbayu logcat says "No such file or directory "